# Cordova and ionic - project setup

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I'm using ionic to create an app, and I need to use cordova as well...
now, I know that if you install ionic, and then start an ionic project, everything should be cloned into the folder that you define.

But what if I have already a project (pulled from a repository) in which there are no node_modules, cordova and bower? I can run `npm install` to install all the node modules, and same for `bower install`, but what about cordova?

All I was able to find was this: `cordova create app` (where app is my current NOT empty project) and the result was:

> Error: Path already exists and is not empty:

On the cordova website i wasn't able to find anything regarding initialize cordova into a non empty project.

is this even possible? any suggestions?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way I can think of is create a new blank Ionic project.

Use the command `$ ionic start myApp blank` for that.

This will setup everything ionic/cordova related, so the next step would be to manually copy the files from the pulled repo and put them in the correct location in the newly created project.

If it's working, you can continue installed some node/bower dependencies to really start developping.

Note: I'm not sure if this is the best/fastest way, but it should do the trick (if you have some ionic/web experience already)

Comment: Yeah, I already though about doing something like this, i just wanted to know if there is a "proper" better way to do it, otherwise yes, i'm sure i'll go for this option. It just seams a bit of a "hack" :)

Comment: At the end I used this suggestions. Thanks

Comment: Great it worked out, it is indeed a bit hackey, but it's the safest way to do it, otherwise you would have a lot of useless files and stuff

Answer (score 0):

```
ionic start ChatApp blank --type=ionic1
```

will work for ionic1 and also for some people

[ionic and cordova not installing on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39779474/ionic-and-cordova-not-installing-on-windows/51778384#51778384)