# ionic and cordova not installing on windows

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

i'm trying to install ionic but i'm failed to do that..i had install **node.js** but now these 2 things are not installing on my laptop. kindly help me as i don't know what to do in such condition.
Following command i tried to use:

```
npm install -g cordova ionic
sudo npm install -g cordova ionic
npm install -g cordova 
npm install -g  ionic
```

[image: ionic installation just stuck here for hours]

Comment: From your screenshot, it looks like they are installing, is the progress bar not moving?

Comment: yes!!! it's not moving

Answer (score 1):

To start developing an ionic project:

**Prereqs**

Include [Git for Windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win) for windows which is what I assume you are using based on the image in your question. After you install Git (and npm which you also stated was installed) go to the directory where you want to create the project and run the following.

1. `npm install -g cordova`
2. `npm install -g ionic`
3. `ionic start appName blank`
4. `cd appName`
5. `ionic platform add android`
6. `ionic build android`
7. `ionic emulate android`

Also you can run in web browser using `ionic serve` or a web browser with iOS and Android using `ionic serve --lab`

If you want to emulate the Android device, make sure you have a system_image installed of the device you want. Guide [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html#viewing) to do that.

**EDIT:**

Run `npm --v` and you should see the version you are running, if not then npm isn't installed correctly. Install it globally and run the process again.

Comment: i have github for windows..the problem is progress bar not moving anywhere

Comment: @AzharCh If that is the case it sounds like a connection problem. Are you behind a proxy and if so is it configured?

Answer (score 0):

To add to Sam5487 answer.
If you are behind corporate proxy, then you should first these commands with appropriate changes.

```
  npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
  npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
```

Then

```
 npm install -g cordova

 npm install -g ionic

 ionic start <your app name>blank --type=ionic1

 ionic cordova platform add android
```

For web browser testing you can use

```
 ionic serve
```

After you are happy with your changes

```
 ionic build android

 ionic emulate android
```

All related information can be found at

https://jjasonclark.com/how-to-setup-node-behind-web-proxy/
https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/preface.html